# Check Oracle Query Execution Count

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing, rdbms

I'm using this loop to parse XML.

```
        FOR elementdetails in     
                (SELECT ExtractValue(Value(elementdetails),'/details/Id/text()') AS Id,
                        Extract(Value(elementdetails),'/details/GrpId') AS Idgrp,
                        ExtractValue(Value(elementdetails),'/details/SrCd/text()') AS PId  
           FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(Block,'/Records/Body/details)))
                       elementdetails)
```

Format of xml :

```
    <Records>
      <Body>
        <details>
          <Id>1</Id>
          <GrpId>15</GrpId>
          <SrCd>2</SrCd>
    </details>
    <details>
          <Id>2</Id>
          <GrpId>5</GrpId>
          <SrCd>6</SrCd>
    </details>
         </Body>
    </Records>
```

After parsing I'm passing the element details values like this: `elementdetails.Id` to other procedure. 
So, in above example loop will run twice.
My question is: whenever loop runs, it does the select query to parse the whole xml or only the first details tag and then the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FOR loop query executed once.
Then Oracle iterate using cursor.
(it execute loop body for each row of query result).